# TestNG XML: Groups still being executed although failure occurred in the dependent group

Tags: java, automation, testng, testng.xml

i've setup my xml so it will run groups which depends-on different group in order to run.
when the different group fails, i would expect that the groups won't run, but it is still running.
here is my code:

```
<test name="Test1">
    <parameter name="testedApp" value="someValue"/>
    <groups>
        <run>
            **<include name="Test1"/>**
            <exclude name="TestX"/>
            <exclude name="TextY"/>
        </run>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Service Health Check -->
            **<group name="Test1" depends-on="ServiceHealthCheck"/>**
        </dependencies>
    </groups>
    <packages>
        <package name="project.auto.tests.api...*"/>(package)
    </packages>
    <classes>
        <!-- Service Health Check -->
        <class name=".....PbServiceHealthCheckTest"/>(class)
    </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: TestNG 6.14.3 has a bug which prevenr the "depends-on" to work correctly.
Upgrade to TestNG 7.1.0 solved the issue.

Comment: You might want to accept your answer so that the question gets closed.